# How to save Generic Type class instances in a collection in C#

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have a Generic Class Report.

```
 class Report<TValue1, TValue2>
   {
    public List<TValue1> AvailableValues { get; private set; }
    public List<TValue2> DefaultValues { get; private set; }
    public void SetValues(List<TValue1> availableValues, List<TValue2> defaultValues)
    {
        AvailableValues = availableValues;
        DefaultValues = defaultValues;
    }
   }
```

From client Report class gets instantiated like shown below.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<String> names = new List<String>();
        names.Add("asdf");
        names.Add("asd");

        List<Int32> ids= new List<Int32>();
        ids.Add(1);
        ids.Add(2);

        Report<String, Int32> report1 = new Report<string, int>();
        report1.SetValues(names, ids);

        List<Boolean> names1 = new List<Boolean>();
        names1.Add(false);
        names1.Add(true);

        List<Int32> ids2 = new List<Int32>();
        ids.Add(11);
        ids.Add(12);

        Report<Boolean, Int32> report2 = new Report<Boolean, Int32>();
        report2.SetValues(names1,ids2);
     }
```

Now i want to Keep report1 and report2 instance in a collection so that they can be consumed later.
  Please suggest how to store them and get report instances later in efficient way.

Comment: How will you use these instances later? Why, in spite of the fact that they share no common aspects, do you want them stored in a single collection? No useful suggestion can be provided without more details.

Comment: Too many options with too many pros/cons to suggest something without a little more information from you on what you're trying to do and why.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is nothing incommon between the types you need to store them into a collection of `objects`.

Comment: There are other possibilities: List<dynamic>, List<ISomeCommonInterface>, List<CommonBaseClass>, etc.

Comment: @dodexahedron: `List<dynamic>` IS `List<object>`. Also, as Selman22 said, if there is no common interfaces, `List<ISomeCommonInterface` wont really work ;)

Comment: Totally misread the posted code. I missed that he was just using ints and strings in his generic class and was making the assumption that the classes getting used in his generic class were not shown. My bad.